# Print multiple counters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter, maps, counter

First: Sorry for my english....I was programming an application in Node.js , which used Twitter data streaming and locate them on Google Maps, the point is that I was unable to print different counter depending on each tweet. The problem is that I want count each markers separately and write the amount in each of the strong tags, but ends up counting all the markers and print the amount on my strong tags, part of the code I use is this:

```
var green = document.getElementById("strong_green");
var blue = document.getElementById("strong_blue");
var orange = document.getElementById("strong_orange");
var yellow = document.getElementById("strong_yellow");
var red = document.getElementById("strong_red");
var purple = document.getElementById("strong_purple");

...


    if (/musica/.test(tweetText) || /música/.test(tweetText) || /Musica/.test(tweetText) || /Música/.test(tweetText))
        var iconFile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
        marker.setIcon(iconFile)
        counter_green++;
        green.innerHTML = counter_green;

    if (/cine/.test(tweetText) || /Cine/.test(tweetText))
        var iconFile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
        marker.setIcon(iconFile)
        counter_blue++;
        blue.innerHTML = counter_blue;

    if (/pintura/.test(tweetText) || /Pintura/.test(tweetText))
        var iconFile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png';
        marker.setIcon(iconFile)
        counter_orange++;
        orange.innerHTML = counter_orange;  

    if (/teatro/.test(tweetText) || /Teatro/.test(tweetText))
        var iconFile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
        marker.setIcon(iconFile)
        counter_yellow++;
        yellow.innerHTML = counter_yellow;

    if (/cultura/.test(tweetText) || /Cultura/.test(tweetText))
        var iconFile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
        marker.setIcon(iconFile)
        counter_red++;
        red.innerHTML = counter_red;

    if (/evento/.test(tweetText) || /Evento/.test(tweetText))
        var iconFile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png';
        marker.setIcon(iconFile)
        counter_purple++;
        purple.innerHTML = counter_purple;
```

Comment: The space in '+ +' in your counter increments is a syntax error. Take the space out.

Comment: The whitespace in the tag ids in your document.getElementById() calls may also be a problem, if the tagname in the HTML code does not have the matching whitespace (e.g. " strong_green " vs. "strong_green")

Comment: the HTML is formed with div.innerHTML and is OK